# How can I compare two times in mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two fields `timeIn` and `arrivalTime` in my mongodb collection. The timeIn field represents the time in which a user should arrive, and the arrivalTime represents the actual time of arrival.

```
timeIn:"2020-05-24T18:31:00.000Z",
arrivalTime:2020-05-27T02:36:37.558+00:00
```

How can I compare `timeIn` and `arrivalTime` so that I can mark those who arrives after timeIn as 'Late'.

```
$project: {
    name: 1,
    isPresent: {
        $cond: {
            if: {
                $lte: [ISODate("$arrivalTime"), ISODate("$timeIn")]
            },
            then: true,
            else: false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're storing the dates as string you can compare the two (as strings) assuming you ensure they are always in the same format and timezone.

```
$project: {
    name: 1,
    isPresent: {
        $cond: {
            if: {
                $lte: ["$arrivalTime","$timeIn"]
            },
            then: true,
            else: false
        }
    }
}
```

With that said this is not recommended as "ensuring" such things I feel is not a good approach. So what else can you do?

1. Save the dates as `Date`. this will require you to update your code and database but will be In my opinion the best long term solution.
2. If you're using Mongo version 3.6+ you can use Mongo's [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)

```
$project: {
    name: 1,
    isPresent: {
        $cond: {
            if: {
                $lte: [{$dateFromString: {dateString: "$arrivalTime"}}, 
                       {$dateFromString: {dateString: "$timeIn"}}]
            },
            then: true,
            else: false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is that possible to compare time without considering date?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: In this case, arrivalTime updated everyday but timeIn is set once. So if we consider date also, from the next day onwards arrivalTime will be always greater, right?

Comment: Ah if this is used daily then yes. i'm not sure what the logic you're aiming for but you'll have to account for that.

Comment: How can I do that? Do you have any idea?

Comment: again i'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but it sounds like you just care about the hour if that's the case maybe add an hour field like `07:59` and compare those. if those were date objects you can have used Mongo's `$hour` to do it. which is a great example of why option 1 is the recommended option.

Comment: Thank you. Actually these fields are from two collections, workshift and dailyReports.